# How to set a style when using a view from imported library

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView) to obtain round images. I want to create a style to control the `CircularImageView` view.

```
 <style name="vircularImageView" >
        <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/cardViewImagesize</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/cardViewImagesize</item>
        <item name="app:civ_border_color">#000000</item>
 </style>
```

The problem is the item `app:civ_border_color`, that gives me an error when compiling.

The attribute `civ_border_color` is specific for this object  `com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView`, so i'm wondering how to solve the problem.

I tried using `parent` but I dont' get any suggestion that matches `CircularImageView`.

Thank you

How can

Comment: See my answer it just the suggestion you can use only this much of line to create a rounded imageview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in styles you **should not** use any prefix for custom attributes, so it should be:

```
<style name="vircularImageView" >
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/cardViewImagesize</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/cardViewImagesize</item>
    <item name="civ_border_color">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this instead of using a big library.

```
RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(Activity.this.getResources(), yourbitmap);
roundedBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
your_imageview.setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable);
```

Comment: Nice solution. Ill try it :)